# Adding an alternative email address to Entity Registration

Tags: entities, emails

I am looking to implement event booking with entity registration.  Currently users of my site have to log in, this then captures their email address from LDAP.

What I would like to do is have it so that when users sign up to an event they can enter an alternative email address for reminders.

I have installed entity registration and created the alternative email field, however how do I go about routing the mail to an alternative address if the user has entered one?

Comment: Perhaps Rules will do what you need.

Comment: I've had a look around at rules and can't figure a proper scenario for this case.  On the other hand I have found that it can email people as soon as they register so that's another problem solved.